# How to Universally Remove the Comma from Each Index Entry

Tags: pdftex, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

This question extends the one recently posed in [How to Selectively Remove the Comma in an Index Entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627748/how-to-selectively-remove-the-comma-in-an-index-entry)

In the above post, it was answered that by inserting `\newcommand\textbfnocomma[2]{\textbf{#1}}` into the preamble, an index entry comma can be removed with the command `\textbfnocomma`.

I am presently working on producing an index of quotations where the said comma seems to be a little out of place; and so, I would like to see what the index looks like with *all* such commas removed.

Consider the code,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\newcommand\textbfnocomma[2]{\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\large
    
Some words. %\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!01@\textbfnocomma{\color{red}{\textit{So entfernen Sie das Komma?---}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!02@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!03@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!04@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!05@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!06@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
    
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index:

[image]

QUESTION: Is it possible, and if so, how may I easily remove the comma from all index entries without resorting to removing them all individually with the preamble command described above? No `textindy` please.

Thank you.

Comment: didn't we start with a modified makeindex style before you asked about controlling individual entries?

Comment: @David Carlisle In the "Selectively Remove" post alluded to above?

Comment: er this I guess https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622091/1090

Comment: @David Carlisle Still confused as to what you mean; however, I see that your updated answer in that post relates to the question I asked here. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the `delim_1` field of [`makeindex`](//ctan.org/pkg/makeindex), since the page numbers you list is at level 1. From [`makeindex.hlp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.hlp):

```
 delim_0          ", "
                          Delimiter to be inserted between  a
                          level  0  key  and  its  first page
                          number (default: comma followed  by
                          a blank).

 delim_1          ", "
                          Delimiter to be inserted between  a
                          level  1  key  and  its  first page
                          number (default: comma followed  by
                          a blank).

 delim_2          ", "
                          Delimiter to be inserted between  a
                          level  2  key  and  its  first page
                          number (default: comma followed  by
                          a blank).

 delim_n          ", "
                          Delimiter to  be  inserted  between
                          two  page  numbers for the same key
                          in any level (default:  comma  fol-
                          lowed by a blank).

 delim_r          "--"
                          Delimiter to  be  inserted  between
                          the   starting   and   ending  page
                          numbers of a range.

 delim_t          ""
                          Delimiter to be inserted at the end
                          of a page list.  This delimiter has
                          no effect on entries which have  no
                          associated page list.
```

In short, include/change the following in your preamble:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.ist}
delim_1 " "
\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex[options=-s \jobname.ist]
```

The above code writes a file `\jobname.ist` - a `makeindex` style file - and changes the default value of `delim_1` to `" "` - a regular space (from `", "`). Then, to use this newly-created style file, pass the option `-s \jobname.ist` to your call to `\makeindex`. If you have page numbers at multiple levels, just add `delim_0`, `delim_2`, ... to the `.ist`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.ist}
delim_1 " "
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex[options=-s \jobname.ist]
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\large
    
Some words.
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!02@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!03@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!04@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!05@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!06@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
    
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer; however, when I run it as is, I get errors. It seems that my TexStudio does not recognize `\begin{document}` nor `begin{filecontents}`. However, when I run it without `[overwrite]`---it seems to work fine. Is `[overwrite]` needed here?

Comment: @mlchristians: Your distribution is probably out-of-date. The `filecontents` functionality (from the [`filecontents` package](//ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)) was absorbed into the LaTeX kernel (Oct 2020), with some minor changes. Some mutually-exclusive options to try: (1) Add `\usepackage{filecontents}` and remove the `[overwrite]` option. (2) Put ``delim_1 " "`` inside a separate `.ist` file, but keep `\makeindex[options=-s \jobname.ist]` in your file. (3) Update your distribution and try again.

Comment: Many thanks @Werner